# Solid mode doesn´t show a texture right

Tags: texturing

I finished the project with texturing and rendering etc, then I moved each file and folder into one to organize them. This had the effect of course the texture got broke, so I added every texture and background back to the project and everything is fine, but in Solid mode, where I switched to Texture in the Viewport shader , the object becomes displayed a different way. In render or Material mode everything is fine, only in solid mode it is displayed incorrectly. I dont why.

I think this doesn´t effect my Project that much, but i whould rather have it right.

[image]

Comment: Texture is shown in this mode only for materials with UV. Check if you have this part correctly unwrapped.

Comment: Solid mode is what it is - solid mode. Maybe try Material Preview Mode for material preview... Does that work?